# ng build compile all angular material modules

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

When I run ng build --prod, all mat modules are compiled Even unused modules

share.module.ts

```
---
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatOptionModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ---
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatMenuModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ---
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatOptionModule,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

What is the mistake, does it affect the bundle size and app loading speed

Comment: I get the same with PrimeNG